# Meaning of に in ～にできる

Tags: grammar

In the sentence,

> これまでの借金を全て帳消し**に出来る**…！！

What is に doing here ?

Comment: Can you guess the connection between 借金(debt) and 帳消し(offset) in meaning?

Comment: What do you mean ? Are you talking about the translation ? I would translate it as : "I could clear the debt !!"

Comment: It seems to me, you can get it with Ben's answer since you understand the grammar.

Answer (score 7):

帳消し is a noun referring to "the state of being cancelled out/wiped clean", and its verbal form 帳消しする is not particularly common. The usual verbal expression for "to wipe the slate clean" is 帳消しにする, and 帳消しにできる is simply the potential equivalent.

In essence, this is the basic usage of XをYにする to mean "to make X Y", which itself is essentially a transitive equivalent of XがYになる "X becomes Y". So for instance:

> ドラえもんが次の大統領になる。
>   Doraemon will become the next President.
>
> ドラえもんを次の大統領にする。
>   I will make Doraemon the next President.
>
> ドラえもんを次の大統領にできる。
>   I can make Doraemon the next President.

帳消し follows the same basic pattern, with 帳消し as the indirect object Y:

> 借金が帳消しになる。
>   The debts will be wiped clean.
>
> 借金を帳消しにする。
>   I will wipe the debts clean.
>
> 借金を帳消しにできる。
>   I can wipe the debts clean.

Comment: I see. Just to make sure, what are the most important XをYにする structures in japanese ? I've only been taught that such a grammar would mean "use something as something" but I don't think it makes any sense in this case.