# Why is に used here?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, particle-に

Just wondering why the second に is being used here

> 現行犯逮捕以外に僕**に**何ができる？

My rough translation is:

> What can I do other than catching them in the act?

I understand the reasoning for the first に but the second one is throwing me as to what its exact grammatic purpose is

Comment: Related/Duplicates: [が and に interchangeability](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/%e3%81%8c-and-%e3%81%ab-interchangeability-and-difference-in-meaning), [Meaning of に in ～にできる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/53596/meaning-of-%E3%81%AB-in-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B/53597)

Comment: What else would you put here?